# Prevent parts of html from loading in mobile

Tags: html

I have used css and media queries till now to prevent images from loading. Now i have to requirement to prevent parts of html, scripts from loading in mobile browsers.
Here is how i used to prevent images from loading

```
@media (min-width:601px) {
   .image {
      background-image: url(http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/img.jpg);
      width:700px;
      height:350px;
   }
}
```

Any suggestions for HTML and JavaScript ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just can prevent HTML parsing in browser by [`CDATA`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) or [`HTML comments`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_comment.asp). But you must change your `server side/template generated` code to prevent loading any HTML code.

Also you can't prevent loading script from `script` tag `src` attribute. You can use `window.matchMedia` and `lazy-load/async` for loading script:

```
if (window.matchMedia('min-width:601px')) {
   (function (callback) {
       var script = document.createElement('script');
       script.src ='url';
       script.onload = callback;
       document.documentElement.firstChild.append(script);
   })(callback/*if needed*/)
}
```

Or using [`requirejs`](http://requirejs.org):

```
if (window.matchMedia('min-width:601px')) {
   var someModule = require('moduleName_or_path');
}
```

Also you can use [enquirejs](http://css-tricks.com/enquire-js-media-query-callbacks-in-javascript/).

Comment: Great approach. Is this feature available in requirejs?

Comment: I edit my answer and add link to [enquirejs](http://css-tricks.com/enquire-js-media-query-callbacks-in-javascript/). I think enquirejs is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: 
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

If you want to use javascript of jQuery:
[What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery)

Of course add a `display: none` on the element you want to hide after detecting if on mobile device.

Comment: Hi want to prevent them from loading to save bandwidth. Not hide

Answer (score 0):

Here's some JavaScript code that you can run to include desktop-only JS and remove unwanted HTML elements from mobile browsers.

```
if (window.innerWidth > 601) {
    //Run JS code that is to be loaded only on desktop browsers
    console.log("This will run only in desktop browsers");
}

if (window.innerWidth < 601) {
    //Remove HTML elements not to be shown in mobile devices
    document.getElementById("extra-info").remove();

}
```